# Changing GtkButton color when GtkWindow is changed

Tags: c, gtk

I am trying a simple sample Gtk program and using GtkTable to align my widgets.

My layout should be:

Window background is black. The buttons should be white while the text on the buttons should be black. All labels should be white so they can be seen against the black window background.

With this in mind. Here is what I have done so far.

Code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <stdio.h>      /* standard in and output*/


typedef struct cmd_widgets{
    GtkWidget *button1;
    GtkWidget *combo;
    GtkWidget *label;

}my_cmd_widgets;

static gboolean close_application( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event, gpointer   data )
{
  gtk_main_quit ();
  return FALSE;
}

static void UpdateChoice( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    my_cmd_widgets *widgrp;
    widgrp = (my_cmd_widgets *)data;
    gchar *text =  gtk_combo_box_get_active_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(widgrp->combo));
    GString *val = g_string_new("You have chosen :  ");
    g_string_append(val, text);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(widgrp->label), val->str);
    g_free(text);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *table;

  GtkWidget *label1;
  GtkWidget *label2;
  GtkStyle  *style;

  GtkWidget *align;

  my_cmd_widgets grp_widgets;
  GtkWidget *image;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  gtk_rc_parse("fonts.rc");

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Tour App");
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);

  table = gtk_table_new(7, 1, FALSE);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);


  label1 = gtk_label_new("Our Tour Package Offers");
  align = gtk_alignment_new(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(align), label1);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), align, 0, 1, 1, 2, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0, 10);


  label2 = gtk_label_new("Select City: ");
  align = gtk_alignment_new(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(align), label2);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), align,0, 1, 2, 3, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0, 0);
  gtk_widget_show(align);
  grp_widgets.combo = gtk_combo_box_new_text();
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(grp_widgets.combo), "Paris");
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(grp_widgets.combo), "London");
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(grp_widgets.combo), "Tokyo");
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(grp_widgets.combo), "New York");

  /* Creates a new button1. */

   grp_widgets.button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("See Itinerary");

   grp_widgets.label = gtk_label_new("");
   align = gtk_alignment_new(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
   gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(align), grp_widgets.label);
   gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), align,0, 1, 5, 6, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0, 0);
   gtk_widget_show(align);


  image = gtk_image_new ();
  gtk_image_set_from_file (GTK_IMAGE(image), "Images/olympics_logo.gif");

  //column 1
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), image, 0, 1, 0, 1,
      GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 0, 0);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), grp_widgets.combo, 0, 1, 3, 4,
      GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 0, 15);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), grp_widgets.button1, 0, 1, 4, 5,
      GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 15);



  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK (close_application), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(grp_widgets.button1), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (UpdateChoice), (gpointer)&grp_widgets);


  gtk_widget_show(table);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the rc file with properties for TABLE AND WINDOW:

```
style "window"
{
  font_name = "fixed 12"
  bg[NORMAL] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }
}
style "table"
{
  bg[NORMAL] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }
  fg[NORMAL] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }
}

style "container" {
        font_name = "bold 12"
        xthickness = 10
        ythickness = 10
        bg[NORMAL] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }
        fg[NORMAL] = { 1.0, 1.0,1.0 }          
}

style "button" {
        font_name = "bold 12"
        xthickness = 10
        ythickness = 10 
        #bg[NORMAL] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }   
        fg[NORMAL] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }  
}

#widget_class "*GtkButton*" style "button"
widget_class "GtkWindow" style "window"
widget_class "*GtkTable*" style "table"
```

The problem in the above code is, the Button's text(label) remains white when I change the fg to white on either table or window styles. Even after changing the fg to black(as below), the label text on my button remains white. Also how can I stretch the image and all the widgets on the window so that whenever I resize my window all widgets are resized to fit screen as well?

Comment: And what results are you getting, in other words, *what is your question*?

Comment: oops! will EDIT!!!! OMG :) Thanks unwind

Answer (score 1):

> All labels should be white so they can be seen against the black window background.

According to what I've found online:

> GtkLabel Widget is one of a few GTK+ widgets that don't create their
> own window to render themselves into. This menas in order to set the
> bg color for a GtkLabel Widget,you need to change the bg color of its
> parent.

So in that case, for a simple example, I packed only one of the labels in a GtkEventBox.
Code Piece:

```
GtkWidget *eventBox;
...
eventBox = gtk_event_box_new();
  
label1 = gtk_label_new("Our Tour Package Offers");
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(eventBox), label1);
align = gtk_alignment_new(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(align), eventBox);
...
```

simplified rc file:

```
style "window"
{
  font_name = "fixed 12"
  bg[NORMAL] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }
}

style "label"{
  bg[NORMAL] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }
}

widget_class "GtkWindow" style "window"
widget_class "*GtkAlignment*GtkEventBox*" style "label"
```

and result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks fabregaszy. I actually want the text on the labels to be white. With just the foreground color set to white on the table style, the text on labels are shown white. However the label with text "See itinerary" on the button goes white as well. I have edited my post. You can try the above code.

Comment: In your rc file you should try to match the label you want your rc file to affect as precise as possible. Sometimes '*' could be tricky for it may affect the GtkLabel which is the child of a GtkButton(created by gtk_button_new_with_label). I'm also a rookie in GTK, hope it may help you :D

Comment: With widget_class "GtkButton.GtkLabel" style "label" I solved the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ok, its 8 years... but my system theme overrides the rc file...